# Dependencies injection in MethodInterceptor

Tags: java, dependency-injection, aop, guice

I have MethodInterceptor with dependencies. How could I inject them?

[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-guice/browse_thread/thread/a2744812a7a2485f), in 2007, Bob Lee said that this possibility should be included in next release, but I can't find API for this.
[`bindInterceptor`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#bindInterceptor%28com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher%3C?%20super%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%3E,%20com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher%3C?%20super%20java.lang.reflect.Method%3E,%20org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor...%29) method requires instances instead of classes.

Comment: did you see this.http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=88

Comment: They are talking abt the sample here.http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP#Injecting_Interceptors

Comment: @doc_180, I sow it. But I missed `requestInjection`. Thanks a lot. Please, post it as answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [Guice FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions):

In order to inject dependencies in an AOP MethodInterceptor, use `requestInjection()` alongside the standard bindInterceptor() call.

```
public class NotOnWeekendsModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    MethodInterceptor interceptor = new WeekendBlocker();
    requestInjection(interceptor);
    bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(NotOnWeekends.class), interceptor);
  }
}
```

Another option is to use `Binder.getProvider` and pass the dependency in the constructor of the interceptor.

```
public class NotOnWeekendsModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
     bindInterceptor(any(),
         annotatedWith(NotOnWeekends.class),
         new WeekendBlocker(getProvider(Calendar.class)));
  }
}
```

Comment: How do we do this if the `WeekendBlocker` has `@Inject` on the constructor? Ideally I would like a method `newInstance(WeekendBlocker.class)`, where WeekendBlocker was previously bound using `bind(WeekendBlocker.class)`.